# angular.min.js:sourcemap:125 Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a register/login page with AngularJS using a restful-api but when I run it i get this error:

> angular.min.js:sourcemap:125 Error: [$injector:unpr]

at the link provided https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.7/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$resourceProvider%20%3C-%20$resource%20%3C-%20AppLoginCtrl with the error I can't see what is wrong with my code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('AppLoginCtrl', ["$resource", "$scope", function ($resource, $scope) {

            var apiBase = "/api";

            var RegisterUser = $resource(apiBase + "/createUser", {}, {save: {method: 'POST',
                    responseType: 'json'}});
            var Login = $resource(apiBase + "/login", {});

            $scope.Succes = "Welcome back. Go to next step to continue your reservation";
            $scope.acceptUser = false;

            //Register form
            $scope.username = "";
            $scope.firstname = "";
            $scope.lastname = "";
            $scope.password = "";
            $scope.email = "";

            //Login form
            $scope.usernameLogin = "";
            $scope.passwordLogin = "";

            $scope.login = function () {
                $scope.error = "";
                $("#loginForm .form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                var loginIsValid = true;
                var inputs = $("#loginForm .form-group input");
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (!inputs[i].validity.valid) {
                        loginIsValid = false;
                        $(inputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    }
                }
                if (loginIsValid) {
                    //$scope.isAuthenticated = true;
                    var login = new Login({});
                    login.username = $scope.usernameLogin;
                    login.password = $scope.passwordLogin;
                    login.$save(function (response) {
                        $scope.user.username = $scope.usernameLogin;
                        $scope.user.password = $scope.passwordLogin;
                        $scope.succes = "Welcome back. Go to next step to continue your reservation";
                        $scope.loginuser();

                    },
                            function () {
                                $scope.error = "Wrong username or password";
                            });
                }
            };

            $scope.register = function () {
                $scope.Error = "";
                $("#registerForm .form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                var registerIsValid = true;
                var inputs = $("#registerForm .form-group input");
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (!inputs[i].validity.valid) {
                        registerIsValid = false;
                        $(inputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-


error");
                        }
                    }
                    if (registerIsValid) {
                        var rs = new RegisterUser({});
                        rs.userName = $scope.username;
                        rs.first = $scope.firstname;
                        rs.last = $scope.lastname;
                        rs.password = $scope.password;
                        rs.email = $scope.email;
                        rs.$save(function (response) {
                            if (response.userName) {
                                $scope.user.username = $scope.username;
                                $scope.user.password = $scope.password;
                                $scope.login();
                                $scope.succes = "User succesfully created.";
                            }
                            else {
                                $scope.error = "Error creating user.";
                            }
                        },
                                function (response) {
                                    $scope.error = response.data.error;
                                });
                    }

                };
     }]);
```

I hope someone con tell me what is wrong with my code because I can't find it..

Edit replacing

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
```

with

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
```

and adding

```
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-
     resource.js"></script>
```

this just gave a different error, I'm not sure what is causing this error i Hope someone can help

this is the error it gave me

```
angular-resource.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of 
   undefined
    at angular-resource.js:8
    at angular-resource.js:857
  angular.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:43
    at p (angular.min.js:8)
    at g (angular.min.js:42)
    at hb (angular.min.js:46)
    at c (angular.min.js:22)
    at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
    at we (angular.min.js:21)
    at angular.min.js:335
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the module (since it's separate):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.8/angular-resource.js">
```

(*It may require matching your* `angular.js` *version*)

And then inject it with:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
```

Comment: Thanks thanks but this didn't work now i have 2 error which I will ad to my question

Comment: @TWOcvfan the order of scripts matter. You need `angular.js` **before** `angular-resource.js` (and any other dependencies), because your "myApp" module is using "ngResource" module and therefore _dependant_ on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the resource module in your page. he file can be downloaded on the AngularJS site, or with the CDN, it's called angular-resource.js